How to get the input shape of TensorFlow layers?
Having a model instance as input, I would like to create a function that prints the input shape of the model layers. I am aware of model.layers() but this is not general enough for what I want. Layers in my models might not have a sequential order, and a layer might receive its input from a layer different than the one preceding it.
